# How can I change this query returning multiples records to return a single record containing the concatenation of the original records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I am facing the following problem. I am using **MySql**

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
        LSSN.livestock_species_name AS species_name,
        LSFT.feed_type_name         AS feed_type_name,
        LSFT.description            AS feed_description
FROM LivestockDetails AS LSD
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies AS LSS
      ON LSD.live_stock_species_id = LSS.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpeciesName AS LSSN
      ON LSS.id = LSSN.livestock_species_id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
      ON LSSN.language_id = LNG.id   
INNER JOIN LsFeedDetails AS LSFD
      ON LSD.ls_feed_details_id = LSFD.id
INNER JOIN LsFeedTypes AS LSFT
      ON LSFD.ls_feed_types_id = LSFT.id
WHERE LSD.live_stock_species_id = 3
AND LSD.ls_area_id = 2
AND LSD.ls_action_type_id = 1
AND LSD.ls_message_id is null
AND LNG.id = 1
```

that returns these records:

```
species_name            feed_type_name                         feed_description
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Local Cows              Rangeland                              Grasses         
Local Cows              Crop residues                          Maize and sorghum Stover, rice, wheat, and sugar bean straw, parts of banana plants, wheat straw
Local Cows              Improved grasses                       e.g. Napier grass
Local Cows              Browsing and herbaceous legumes        Browsing (largely during dry season) and herbaceous legumes (year round)
Local Cows              Planted pastures                       Napier, etc...  
Local Cows              Assorted weeds                         Assorted weeds
```

Ok, these retrieved data are good but I have to modify this query in such a way that:

1) It returns a single record containging a concatenation of the all the information contained in the records retrieved by the previous query.

2) The concatenation have to be something like this:

```
feed_type_name RECORD-1 + (feed_description RECORD-1) + ";" +feed_type_name RECORD-2 + (feed_description RECORD-2) + ";" + feed_type_name RECORD-3 + ";" + (feed_description RECORD-3) + ..............................
```

So, using the previous retrieved data as example something like this:

```
Rangeland (Grasses) ; Crop residues (Maize and sorghum Stover, rice, wheat, and sugar bean straw, parts of banana plants, wheat straw) ; Improved grasses  (e.g. Napier grass) ; ............................................
```

I really have not idea about how to modify my original query to create a query that does something like this. Can you help me to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` and aggreagate by species using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    LSSN.livestock_species_name AS species_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(LSFT.feed_type_name, ' (', LSFT.description, ')') SEPARATOR ';') AS text
FROM LivestockDetails AS LSD
INNER JOIN LivestockSpecies AS LSS
    ON LSD.live_stock_species_id = LSS.id
INNER JOIN LivestockSpeciesName AS LSSN
    ON LSS.id = LSSN.livestock_species_id 
INNER JOIN Languages AS LNG
    ON LSSN.language_id = LNG.id   
INNER JOIN LsFeedDetails AS LSFD
    ON LSD.ls_feed_details_id = LSFD.id
INNER JOIN LsFeedTypes AS LSFT
    ON LSFD.ls_feed_types_id = LSFT.id
WHERE
    LSD.live_stock_species_id = 3
    AND LSD.ls_area_id = 2
    AND LSD.ls_action_type_id = 1
    AND LSD.ls_message_id is null
    AND LNG.id = 1
GROUP BY
    LSSN.livestock_species_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY "species_name" and use GROUP_CONCAT(feed_type_name SEPARATOR ', ') function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

it can be done as follows

```
SELECT  feed_type_name +'('+feed_description +') ; ' as [text()] from 
.....
.....
.....

FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: The OP is using MySQL, not SQL Server.